# phpstorm stuck while synchroning files

Tags: phpstorm

When phpstorm synchroning files, I can't edit files or even shut it down  until sync finished, I was wondering what caused this situation, the files and phpstorm is all on ssd and I'm using phpstorm 9.0, can somebody do me a favor~
[phpstorm synchroning files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKqAl.png)

Comment: Why not use PhpStorm 10?

Comment: @Pang Can I get rid of above problem with phpstorm 10?

Answer (score 0):

It's so strange to process in a same time a synchronization and editing file...
It's so evident that is not possible to edit a file that process in synchronization.

But normally, synchronization is very fast and you don't need edit file in this time door of sync.

perhaps PHPStorm caching files before send at sync and you don't edit those.

PHPStorm 10 has a better indexing process, perhaps you don't have anymore this problem